# How do i prepare an app for submittion to the app store? I *KEEP* getting code signing errors?

Tags: iphone, xcode

If it's not one error, it's another. If it's not that, it's something else. I feel like i've changed so much in my project now just trying to work around the code signing thing that it's all messed up. I follow instructions to the letter and get errors, for example the current one of 'Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile', or if i choose anything other than 'iPhone Distribution (No profiles currently match)', such as 'Team provisioning profile: iPhone Developer [my name] (long number)' or '[my name] Profile: iPhone Developer: [my name] (long number)' i get an error of The entitlements file '/Users/Me/Appfolder/Classes/Entitlements.plist' is missing, which i deleted as a step in 1 tutorial to fixing this mess.

I am totally at my wits end with this now. It should be File > Export. There shouldn't even be this stupid code signing feature. If it's to prevent hackers, hackers can get through it anyway so that nullifies the point. I'm so sick of it. I would appreciate any help with this that anybody could give? Maybe a guide to starting again from scratch with the stupid certificates system or something? I just want to upload my app, that's all i want to do. But because of this silly little complicated process which can so easily go wrong (by the way, made by the company who pride themselves on being straight forward and simple by cutting out the crap) i'm unable to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number one source of my problems - duplicated private keys in the keychain, from Mobile Me syncing and multiple Mac ownership. Here's what I suggest to fix that problem once and for all. (Really - since I did this provisioning has been as easy as I can imagine it being.)

Go to Keychain Access on all your Macs. Delete all your public and private keys. Generate a new certificate request and you should then have exactly one public and private key. NAME this pair by double-clicking in Keychain Access - ruthlessly kill all other keys! (you can't rename it like you do things in the Finder, you have to open the window by double clicking) I called mine "Adam Eberbach's Singleton Private Key". Export that key pair and then import it on your other machines. Keep it forever but of course don't share your private key with others.

The worst thing that happened as a result of deleting all those keys was having to sign into a couple of websites again. I'd like to know if there could be other consequences?

Once you have your one true key pair, go to developer.apple.com and delete all your certificates and provisioning profiles. Generate new certificates with your one true key.

Make sure your bundle identifiers are correct for your apps - you may even want to generate new App IDs.

Once that's all done you generate the provisioning profile. With a valid certificate, app ID and keys you should have no difficulties. The provisioning profile is the bit that really matters but it depends on all the rest. The big test for me is when I drag it into the Xcode Organizer library - if a target then lets me sign a build with a certificate matched by a provisioning profile, I'm pretty confident.

Answer (score 0):

I use a template to make sure I have all my information available. http://loughnanedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/app-store-submitting-template.html