# Valid signing identity matching this profile could not found in key chain

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning, iphone-developer-program

I have downloaded a provisioning profile from my id, but when I drag into Xcode, and then in the provisioning profile section it says

> a valid signing identity matching this profile could not found in key chain

I am trying to download the existing profile and drag into Xcode, but this gives me the problem that how could I deploy my application to the device?

Comment: Hey did you download your private key?

Comment: does your keychain's keys section show your private key?

Comment: i download only provisioning profile from program portal...there are so many private keys in key chain access!i dont know what to do..

Comment: You need to delete the private keys of yours and create a new private key and download it into your keychain that would solve your problem for sure.

Comment: I solved my problem at this

[See the answer to this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete all your private and public keys. Create one new one by using the assistant to request a certificate...

Before you do anything else name the key by double clicking on it and typign a name that identifies it as the one key you will keep.

Delete all others.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5384413/189804) which you might have found with a quick search, from earlier today.

Answer (score 3):

For the error:

> Valid signing identity not found

see Apple's [published steps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_FAQ-WHAT_DOES__VALID_SIGNING_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND__MEAN_AND_HOW_DO_I_RESOLVE_IT_) to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday and solved it successfully. It took me almost a week to figure out the process.

I think your keychain does not possess a valid developer certificate or Apple WWDRCa certificate. To solve this download your developer certificate and drop it into your keychain. Then download the Apple WWDRCA certificate and again drop it into your keychain.

Remember that you must have your private key along with your developer certificate. By now, your keychain will have a matching profile. Now drop your provisioning profile in your Xcode and see. It should work.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Private key is not along with my developer certificate i tried couple of times by revoking the exiting certificate. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem yesterday.For some reason i deleted my keys,because of that my provisioning profiles were with warning "valid signing identity not found".

As i worked on push notification previously i have saved  "X.p12"file from private key  .if u saved that then u have to double click on that and give that password that u given  while saving it. that's it my provision profiles are valid now :).